# Calls from shared object to main app are broken if I build with QtCreator

Tags: c, qt-creator, dlopen

System spec: Ubuntu 16.04, QtCreator 3.5.1 based on Qt5.5.1

In a C project I'm using `dlopen` and friends to load a shared library. The library uses some machinery from the main application.
Now, if I compile manually from terminal, everything works just fine. When I use QtCreator to build the project, calls from the library to the main application fail with the following error:
**/Programming/C/emme_1/emme_1: symbol lookup error: /Programming/C/emme_1/modtest/test.so: undefined symbol: pop**. Here pop is a function in the main application which is named emme_1. Please note that the error happens only if the library's function calls another function inside the main application. If the library's function is empty and is called from the application, it works.

This is my very simple .pro file:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -DTRACE_ASM
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -rdynamic
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -ldl
LIBS +=  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so
```

I believe it contains all it's needed for the requested functionality, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe it contains all it's needed for the requested functionality, but maybe I'm missing something.

You *must* be missing something since the setup doesn't work.

Note that `-rdynamic` and `-ldl` are linker flags, not compile flags. You'll want to move them to `QMAKE_LFLAGS`.

You can *look* at the final link command, and verify that `-rdynamic` is *not* in it. Once you manage to get it there, things will work again.

Comment: Thhaaanks. You know what it bothers me? Is the fact that when I looked at the compiler output -rdynamic was there, so I didn't worry much about using a wrong variable. Also -ld was there. Also the linker didn't report any linking errors.